# C# query with 3 AND conditions

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have 3 combobox that take there information from MS Access database. I want to select data from database according to the values of the combo boxes.

I wrote this query:

```
string query = "select * from products where category='" + comboBox1.Text + "' and subcategory='" + comboBox2.Text + "' and size='" + comboBox3.Text + "'";
```

But it gives me the following exception:

> IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).

Can you help me?

Full code:

```
connection.Open(); 
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(); 
command.Connection = connection; 
string query = "select * from products where category='" + comboBox1.Text + 
    "' and subcategory='" + comboBox2.Text + "' and size='" + comboBox3.Text + "'"; 
command.CommandText = query; 
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command); 
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
da.Fill(dt); 
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; 
connection.Close();
```

Comment: The error is certainly not related with code of line you pasted. How are you accessing the DB? Post the call stack

Comment: btw, your code is vulnerable to sql injection. please read about it

Comment: connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;

            string query = "select * from products where category='" + comboBox1.Text + "' and subcategory='" + comboBox2.Text + "' and size='" + comboBox3.Text + "'";
            command.CommandText = query;
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

          
            connection.Close();

Comment: Edit your question to include the code!

Comment: You can put your code in the question itself it's easier to read. One problem i identify is that you do not have a connection string - does it exist for MS Access? try to get full working examples from internet, i'd say, that have the necessary plumbing

Comment: i am trying to post my code but it gives me error that i have to put spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing since **size** is a reserved word in *MS Access*, it is throwing that error.

See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208875(v=office.12).aspx) for list of reserved words in Access.

Try changing the *column name*. Also, try to use parameterized query to prevent sql injection. 
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759516/sql-injection-prevention-with-microsoft-access-and-vb-net) on how to use parameterized query in Access.

Comment: No worries buddy. Please mark it as answer if it answers your query.

Comment: As an alternative to renaming the column, you can access it by using backticks (`) around the column name.