# What am I doing wrong with this C# .NET WinForms application?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ms-access

I am trying to edit an Access DB_. For some reason I cannot insert anything.  I believe my code is correct. The connection string is correct (though for security purposes I put a fake one for this post). At the end, I do not get the `MessageBox` like I am supposed to at the end of the function. Nothing was added to the *Access DB* either.

Any reason why this might be?

```
namespace TestBuild
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users...\Documents\TestDB.accdb");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into table1 values('"+textBox1.Text+"','"+textBox2.Text+"')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("record inserted successfully");  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a try / catch and see if there is an exception being thrown.  Or run your code in debug mode and step through it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Injection prevention with Microsoft Access and VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759516/sql-injection-prevention-with-microsoft-access-and-vb-net)

Comment: Are you sure that your event handler has been called? If you don't have any exceptions on that code then perhaps your code has not been called. Put a breakpoint on the first line and confirm that your event handler runs

Comment: If you don't want to use the debugger, add a messagebox call as the first line in that click handler: do you see that message when you click the button?

Comment: @arekenny3 - any luck getting things working?  Did you refactor to add a try/catch block (important)? Were you able to step through the code and identify the exact point of failure?  Using the debugger, did you confirm that Button1_Click() is actually being called?

Comment: Yes. Unusual though.
When I went to the [Design], I double clicked on the button and it auto made a button1_Click_1 function for me. 
My question, If i were to delete the function and make the function from scratch named the same thing, would it be the same?  The reason why I ask this is because I am wondering if there is anything else that I don't know about going on in the background of my code? Is it pointing to a variable without me knowing it in the background. 
I think if I were to delete & create from scratch with no change, I think it would be pointing to the same variable. Correct?

Comment: I think you're asking how your "Button1_Click(()" function is tied to the actual button-press event.  If you look in your "Form.Designer.cs", you should see a line like this: `this.Button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button1_Click);`  So yes, you can "delete and create from scratch" Or create a completely different function, if you want.  Just be sure to [delegate](https://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html) with `+=`.  PS: please "upvote" and/or "accept" my response if it was helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Suggestion - please consider refactoring your code as follows, and step through it, a line at a time, in the MSVS debugger:

```
    string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users...\Documents\TestDB.accdb";

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sql = "insert into table1 values('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')";
        OleDbCommand cmd= new OleDbCommand(sql);
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connString)) {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("record inserted successfully");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
   }
```

PS:

If you wanted to use prepared statements, you'd change your code to something like this:

```
string sql = "insert into table1 values(@param1, @param2)";
...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", textBox2.Text);
con.Open();
cmd.Prepare();     
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You can read more about techniques and guidelines for mitigating SQL injection here:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Here is another good article:

[Best Practices for Using ADO.NET (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.prepare(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This code is just as vulnerable to Sql injection as the original.

Comment: Agree with StuartD, edit the answer to put the parameterised version as the only option. Also the `cmd` is `IDisposable` so should be in a `using` block. And you may want to take a look at [Can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).